# SML: Create a list from a list of tuples with the second element of each tuple

Tags: sml

Hello I'm new at SML and I've been trying to write a function that gets as a parameter a list (in my case the list prussia) which has tuples with two ints and a string, my function has to create a list with all the years that appear in the list without repetitions (2nd element of each tuple of the list). I have to do it creating two functions (append_if_new takes a year of the list and adds it in the list, it works) and year has to do it for all the tuples in the list, i tried it using foldl but i get a tycon mismatch.

Pd. to do it i have to use the function map, filter or fold and i can move append_if_new functionalities to the year function. I think the error is in the fold call where the function i pass as parameter is not the type of function i should pass but I'm not sure what is the problem. Thanks

```
    val prussia =
  [(0,1875,"G"),(2,1876,"G"),(2,1877,"G"),(1,1878,"G"),(0,1879,"G"),
   (0,1880,"G"),(1,1881,"G"),(1,1882,"G"),(0,1883,"G"),(3,1884,"G"),
   (0,1885,"G"),(2,1886,"G"),...] : (int * int * string) list

fun append_if_new (lista:(int*int*string)list): int list =
    let 
        val lista2 = []
        val x = hd lista
        val z = #2x
    in
        if (List.exists (fn y => y = z) lista2) 
        then lista2
        else lista2@[z]
    end

fun years (lista:(int*int*string)list): int list =
    List.foldl append_if_new 0 lista
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create a list with all the years that appear in the list without repetitions
>
> (2nd element of each tuple of the list)

You can create a list with repetitions using `map` and filter duplicates afterwards:

```ml
fun year_of (_, year, _) = year
fun member (y, xs) = List.exists (fn x => y = x) xs
fun nub [] = []
  | nub (x::xs) = if member (x, xs)
                  then nub xs
                  else x :: nub xs

fun years records = nub (map year_of records)
```

Here `nub` has an asymptotic running-time complexity of *O(n²)*, which is bad and unnecessary. You can also go straight ahead and fold the list such that you never insert the duplicates to begin with:

```ml
fun member (y, xs) = List.exists (fn x => y = x) xs

fun years records =
    let
      fun insert ((_, year, _), years) =
          if member (year, years)
          then years
          else year :: years
    in
      foldr insert [] records
    end
```

but the asymptotic running time is the same, and it is slightly more obscure to read. If you want to filter duplicates in an efficient way, you have to use a more efficient data structure to manage duplicates, like a tree-based set or similar. In Haskell, this is the difference between [`nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) and [`nubOrd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrd).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- your initial value for the fold is wrong - since the result should be a list, the initial value must also be a list;
- your `append_if_new` function has both too few arguments and too many bugs.

If you substitute the let-bound definitions, `append_if_new` becomes

```
fun append_if_new (lista:(int*int*string)list): int list =
    if List.exists (fn y => y = #2 (hd lista)) [] 
    then []
    else []@[#2 (hd lista)]
```

Since the condition is always false - you will never find anything in the empty list - and `[] @ xs` is equivalent to `[xs]`, we can reduce that further to

```
fun append_if_new (lista:(int*int*string)list): int list =
    [#2 (hd lista)]
```

which is clearly not correct - this function will always produce a list whose only element is the year of the first entry.

Example:

```
- append_if_new prussia;
val it = [1875] : int list
```

The function you pass to `foldl` takes *two* things - "the current element" and "the results so far" - and combines them to produce the "next" result.
Like this:

```
fun add_if_new ((_,y,_), so_far) = if List.exists (fn z => y = z) so_far 
                                   then so_far 
                                   else y :: so_far;
```

Test:

```
- add_if_new ((1,2,3), []);
val it = [2] : int list
- add_if_new ((1,2,3), [3]);
val it = [2,3] : int list
- add_if_new ((1,2,3), [2]);
val it = [2] : int list
```

and:

```
fun years (lista: (int*int*string) list): int list =
    List.foldl add_if_new [] lista
```

Test:

```
- years [(12,0, "G"), (12,1,"G"), (12,0,"G")];
val it = [1,0] : int list
```